# Drupal csv file not readable

Tags: files

I have a module which reads in csv file and adds records to the database. It is working properly on localhost. I am able to upload the file and read and then display the result. But, on my server, i am able to upload the file but this piece of code fails, while reading the file.

```
 $file_handle = fopen($file_url, "r");
 while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
 $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
 print_r($line_of_text);
}
```

I realized that it might be a permission issue so , i checked that folder has got 0777 permission where as i am not able to give recursive permission to files, files have permission of 0664. and i get access denied when i try to give it different permission, i am on ubuntu server. 
After i checked

```
 $file_handle = fopen($file_url, "r");
 var_dump($file_handle);
```

On localhost i got: resource(90, stream), whereas on my server i got bool(false).

Comment: Try putting print_r(error_get_last());  (that should print the last error your code generated) after your fopen call, and update your answer with the results.

Answer (score 0):

[Node Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_import), and [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) are two solutions I've used recently to import content. they may work with while you maintion that your module read from csv and store in DB